# Universal app Splitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios5, ipad

Hello I'm making a universal `iOS` app. I use `UINavigationControllers` on the `iPhone` and now I have a "menu" `UIViewController` from which I want to push to a `UISplitViewController`. Is this even possible? How would I do that?

I've been getting this error:

```
Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller <UINavigationController: 0x1fd6b930>.
```

Will this app get rejected by Apple because the UISplitViewController`enter code here` always must be the root controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No you can't push a `UISplitViewController` on a navigation controllers stack. Also be aware that the `UISplitViewController` is only available on the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, UISpliViewController has to be the root (top) viewController in the app.